# Storing lots of files

Tags: postgresql, cassandra, filesystems, bigdata

I need to store a lot of files (like millions per day). On average, a file is 20 KB. I also need to store some meta-data for these files (date, source, classification etc.) I need to be able to access and retrieve the files according to queries on metadata (No joins, only filtering with WHERE clauses). Writes must be fast, read times are not as important.

As far as I understand, I have 3 possible ways of storing data:

- Use an RDBMS (e.g. PostgreSQL) to store meta-data and store file paths. Execute queries then read matching files from file system
- Use only Cassandra (my company uses Cassandra). Store meta-data and file content on Cassandra.
- Use Postgres + Cassandra together. Store meta-data and Cassandra keys on Postgres, query Postgres and retrieve Cassandra keys,then get actual file content from Cassandra

What are the advantages, disadvantages for these options? I am thinking I should go with option 2 but cannot be sure.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on the size of your files. Storing large files in Cassandra generally isn't the best solution. You'd have to chunk your files at some point to store the content in separate columns using wide rows. In this case it would be better to use a distributed file system like ceph.

But if files are only 20k, the overhead using a distributed FS will not be worth it and Cassandra will do a good job storing this amount of data in a single column as a blob. You just need to be aware of the memory footprint while working with those rows. Each time you retrieve such a file from Cassandra, the whole content will be loaded into the heap, if you don't use chunking using a clustering key.

Comment: What about option 3? One of my colleagues suggested that method but it doesn't make any sense to me. If I use a relational db to store meta-data about files that I will use in my queries, then what is the point of using Cassandra? I am already waiting for Postgresql to run the query, then I am adding the delay for asking returned Ids to Cassandra and wait for its results. Has he got any point that I don't understand?

Comment: No, doesn't make a lot of sense to me either.